# how to insert records into database using sqlalchemy.asyncio and get the inserted keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to insert records into the postgreSQL (or any db) in my Python code (FastAPI) and get the inserted pk back, could not find an understandable solution based on sessions in [SqlAlchemy asyncio](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#synopsis-orm). So, I would like to be sure my code is bug free for multiple concurrent users/calls. It works fine with a couple of user but not sure it will work fine in a busy environment!

```
async def insert_stmt(stmt,async_session: async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession]):
    df=pd.DataFrame({})
    async with async_session() as session:
        try:
            async with session.begin():
                session.add(stmt)
                await session.flush()
                await session.refresh(stmt)
                df= (stmt.PK)
                
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            error = str(e.__cause__)
            await session.rollback()
            raise RuntimeError(error) from e
        finally:
            await session.close()
                     
    return df
```

```
async def post_apps_logs(engine, arg1, arg2):

    result = pd.DataFrame()
     
    try:
        stmt = APP_LOGS(
            arg1=arg1,
            arg2=arg2
        )
        async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)
        result=await insert_stmt(stmt,async_session)
        
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        error = str(e.__cause__)
        raise RuntimeError(error) from e
    return result
```

```
async def post_apps_logs_def( arg1 ,arg2):
   
    return await post_apps_logs(engine=await create_postgresql_engine(),arg1, arg2)
```

```
async def create_postgresql_engine():
   engine =  create_async_engine(ConnectionString, future=True, echo=True) 
   return engine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is things you can do to improve your code: first in `insert_stmt()` you return a DataFrame df but you assign it the value of the primary key. Then there is no need to create a new engine for every call to `post_apps_logs_def()` Just create a single engine and reuse it. With those your code should work more efficiently.

Here is your updated code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
import pandas as pd

# ... (your other imports and table definitions)

async_engine = create_async_engine(ConnectionString, future=True, echo=True)
async_session = sessionmaker(async_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)

async def insert_stmt(stmt, async_session: sessionmaker):
    async with async_session() as session:
        try:
            async with session.begin():
                session.add(stmt)
                await session.flush()
                await session.refresh(stmt)
                pk = stmt.PK
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            error = str(e.__cause__)
            await session.rollback()
            raise RuntimeError(error) from e
        finally:
            await session.close()
    return pk

async def post_apps_logs(arg1, arg2):
    stmt = APP_LOGS(
        arg1=arg1,
        arg2=arg2
    )
    pk = await insert_stmt(stmt, async_session)
    return pd.DataFrame({'PK': [pk]})

async def post_apps_logs_def(arg1, arg2):
    return await post_apps_logs(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what is the point of passing async_engine from post_apps_logs_def to post_apps_logs as engine if it is not being used in this module?

Comment: You welcome :)) and my mistake there is no point in passing the async_engine here, it should be removed, I updated the code.

Comment: thanks a lot, and another question, with the previous code, the total number of conencted session to the db was about 100 (max that I have in my db), but now we the same test it stays on 28-29 concurrent session, so this does not use all the database capacity, isnot this a drawback?

Comment: and when I finish the load test the number of connections does not go down to the initial value ( I am mainly talking about the database (postgresql))

Comment: sorry typo, I am saying " but now with the same test and the provisioned code base on your suggestion the number of connections stays on 28-29 (at the database), so this does not use all the database capacity? isn't this a drawback?"

Comment: it is not necessary a drawback as it reduce ressources usage and it is easier to manage, for the connection not droping it can be because they are not closed properly, you could change your code to explicitely change that, you can also use a connection pool to do that more efficiently, SQLAlchemy got one automaticaly created, you can look into that.

Comment: Thanks will do more investigations, already upvoted, thanks again

Comment: I posted a new question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75893648/an-efficient-way-to-use-async-sqlalchemy-in-python  would be great if I could have your feedback as well