# An efficient way to use Async SQLAlchemy in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, sqlalchemy

I have FastAPI server which connects to PostgreSQL as backend and I implemented two methods to connect to the database as follows:

1- have one async engine which is being used in async sessions for every individual call

2- Create an async engine and (multiple) session(s) for every individual call and dispose the engine after use (when the session ends)

I found the first approach uses less resources and produces less errors (e.g. connection refused, connection aborted, see the below stats) but gives inconsistent user experience (i.e. response time varies significantly), so was wondering if I could have some comments on these two approaches and whether my conclusion is correct.

Method 1 total Failurs:7819+24279+1189+230+10=33527

Method 2 total Failurs:4358+62772+3=67133

**Load Test configurations:**

For the load test I am using Locust with the following configuration

[image]

```
 @task(1)
    def testFastApitask1(self):
        headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        #self.client.post("/predict", data='dfg', headers=headers)
        resp = self.client.get(
            url="/data/campaign/channels/no_log_no_auth",
            auth=None,
            #headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + token_string},
            name='task1'
        )
```

**PostgreSQL query**

```
select max_conn,used,res_for_super,max_conn-used-res_for_super res_for_normal 
from 
  (select count(*) used from pg_stat_activity) t1,
  (select setting::int res_for_super from pg_settings where name=$$superuser_reserved_connections$$) t2,
  (select setting::int max_conn from pg_settings where name=$$max_connections$$) t3;
```

**Baseline connection stats:**
and the result is 13 used connections (100 total) which can consider as the baseline as shown below:

[image]

1. **Method 1:  One async engine which is being used in async sessions for every individual call**

Py code:

```
camp.py
@router.get("/data/campaign/channels/no_log_no_auth",tags=["Campaign methods"])
async def get_channels_in_camp_no_log_no_auth_OP():
    output=await get_channels_in_camp()
    return output

campaign.py
async def get_channels_in_camp():
    df=await camp_channel_unique()
    df=df.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
    return { "channels": df['channel'].to_list() }

campaign_postgresql.py
from engine.engines import async_session
async def camp_channel_unique():

    # create an empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        # create SQL statement with SQLAlchemy
        stmt = select(
            # selecting columns
           distinct( Campain.CHANNEL).label("CHANNEL")
        )
# execute statement
        df=await run_stmt(stmt,async_session)
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        error = str(e.__cause__)
        raise RuntimeError(error) from e
    return df


engine.py

ConnectionString="{}://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(dialect,DS_POSTGRESQL_USER,DS_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD,DS_POSTGRESQL_HOST,DS_POSTGRESQL_PORT,DS_POSTGRESQL_DATABASE)
async_engine=None
async_engine1 =  create_async_engine(ConnectionString, future=True, echo=True)
async_session = sessionmaker(async_engine1, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


Base = declarative_base()
async def run_stmt(stmt, async_session: async_sessionmaker):
  
    async with async_session()  as session:
        try:
            async with session.begin():
                result = await session.execute(stmt)
                rows =   result.fetchall()
                columns =  result.keys()
                if len(rows) > 0:
                    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
                else:
                    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
                df = df.rename(columns=str.lower)
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            error = str(e.__cause__)
            await session.rollback()
            raise RuntimeError(error) from e
        else:
            await session.commit()
        finally:
            await session.close()
            #await engine.dispose()

    return df
```

**Now the performance testing results using Locust and PostgreSQL**

when the number of concurrent users reach 5000 in Locust:

[image]

and the stats:

[image]

**Locust Performance charts:**

[image]

2. **Method 2: An async engine and (multiple) session(s) for every individual call and dispose the engine after use (when the session
   ends)**

Py code:

```
camp.py #same as the previous one
camp.py
@router.get("/data/campaign/channels/no_log_no_auth",tags=["Campaign methods"])
async def get_channels_in_camp_no_log_no_auth_OP():
    output=await get_channels_in_camp()
    return output

campaign.py 
async def get_channels_in_camp():
    """
    Returns unique list of channels' values in the campaign datasets
    """
    df=await camp_channel_unique(engine=await create_postgresql_engine())# I could have not passed the engine but call it in campaign_postgresql.py instead, but would not make a difference
    df=df.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
    return { "channels": df['channel'].to_list() }


campaign_postgresql.py
async def camp_channel_unique(engine):

    # create an empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        # create SQL statement with SQLAlchemy
        stmt = select(
            # selecting columns
           distinct( Campain.CHANNEL).label("CHANNEL")
        )
# execute statement
        df=await run_stmt(stmt,engine)
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        error = str(e.__cause__)
        raise RuntimeError(error) from e
    return df


engine.py
async def create_postgresql_engine():
    engine =  create_async_engine(ConnectionString, future=True, echo=True)
    return engine


async def run_stmt(stmt, engine):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:
        try:
            result = await session.execute(stmt)
            rows =  result.fetchall()
            columns = result.keys()
            if len(rows) > 0:
                df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
            else:
                df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
            df = df.rename(columns=str.lower)
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            error = str(e.__cause__)
            await session.rollback()
            raise RuntimeError(error) from e
        else:
            await session.commit()
        finally:
            await session.close()
            await engine.dispose()

    return df
```

**and now the performance test results:**

PostgreSQL used sessions varied between 90 to 103

[image]

[image]

**Locut results:**

[image]

[image]

**few seconds after stopping the test:**

the connections dropped to the base level

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain more, e.g. why is it more efficient? Based on my understanding sqlalchemy inherits the connection pool's settings from the database