# correct way of running a sql statement in async sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have the below function in FastAPI and all of my endpoints ( more than 20) use this function to get data from the database. If only one statement takes time then all of my endpoints get slow/pause (have to wait). So, a kind of deadlock appears for using this function. I am sure that I am doing something wrong but not sure what. Any help is highly appreciated.

```py
async def run_stmt(stmt, engine):
        print (" +++++-------  time is:", datetime.now() , " and statement is: ", stmt, "-------++++++++++")
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:
            try:
                result = await session.execute(stmt)
                rows =  result.fetchall()
                columns = result.keys()
                if len(rows) > 0:
                    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
                else:
                    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
                df = df.rename(columns=str.lower)
            except SQLAlchemyError as e:
                error = str(e.__cause__)
                await session.rollback()
                raise RuntimeError(error) from e
            else:
                await session.commit()
            finally:
                await session.close()
                await engine.dispose()
    
        return df
```

and the function call history is as follows:

```py
async def camp_channel_unique(engine):
    #form statement
     df=await run_stmt(stmt,engine)

async def get_channels_in_camp():
    df=await camp_channel_unique(engine=await create_postgresql_engine())

async def create_postgresql_engine():
    return engine =  create_async_engine(ConnectionString, future=True, echo=True)
```

Comment: I have done it as well and both approaches stuck in this function. I have explained both ways here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75893648/an-efficient-way-to-use-async-sqlalchemy-in-python

Comment: I intentionally run a very heavy query that needs lots of data being transferred to the API, and when I call this expensive endpoint, the API kind of freezes, and all other endpoints stop working!

Comment: `async` does not make anything parallel - it just enables you to give up time while waiting for io. The only thing that waits for IO in your code is the part that you `await` - all the other functionality - fetching rows, creating dataframes, converting the frames, etc - doesn't give up any time for other coroutines to run. The only place where you're giving up anything is where you're calling `await`, and even then it depends on what the function has implemented. You might want to run more workers instead, so that the load gets distributed across several processes.

Comment: Thank you so much @MatsLindh, Based on your answer, I googled the problem, and it seems (I did a quick try) adding workers to the API call as "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --workers 4" solved my problem. If my understanding is correct would be great if you could add this along with some explanation as the answer. One question, is there any way to make the number of works dynamic?

Comment: You'd usually move on to gunicorn in that case, but generally the number of workers to start with should be about `2*NUM_CORES+1` (from the gunicorn documentation), since you only have a finite amount of CPU to share among those workers anyway. But if you instead want to reduce performance for all users as the number of parallel computations grow, you can exceed that recommendation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I followed your suggested approach and used multiprocessing.cpu_count() to get num_cores dynamically. Thanks again for your help